# calling ajax function in views.py to get the data from database

Tags: django, ajax

I want to fetch data from the database. I am using ajax function to get it in the index.html. How should I call this ajax function to  the views.py so i can display it in view. How should I attain it?

My codes:
**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitData(){
        // Get answer from the input element
        var dt = document.getElementById("major1").value;
        var dtt = document.getElementById("major2").value;
        var dttt = document.getElementById("major3").value;
        var dtttt = document.getElementById("major4").value;
        var dttttt = document.getElementById("major5").value;
        // add the url over here where you want to submit form .
        var url = "{% url 'home' %}";
  
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: {
                'major1': dt,
                'major2': dtt,
                'major3': dttt,
                'major4': dtttt,
                'major5': dttttt,
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data){
                // show an alert message when form is submitted and it gets a response from the view where result is provided and if url is provided then redirect the user to that url.
                alert(data.result);
                if (data.url){
                   window.open(data.url, '_self');
                }
            }
        });
    }
  </script>
```

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    majors = Major.objects.filter(percentages__isnull=False).distinct().order_by("pk")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = request.POST.get('be_nextyr_total')

    line_chart = pygal.Line(width=1500)
    line_chart.title = 'Budget Estimation'  
    context = { 
        "chart": line_chart.render_data_uri(),
        'majors': majors
    }
   
    return render(request, "website/index.html" , context )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing a post request with Ajax, then you have to write in your ajax code like

```
type: "POST",
```

if you want to access your form data in view than you have to write

```
request.POST.get('your_variable_name_like_major1')
```

Comment: Hi @Ankit  I have made my view in this way : def home(request):
majors = Major.objects.filter(percentages__isnull=False).distinct().order_by("pk")
if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
form = request.GET.get('major1')
form = request.GET.get('major2')
form = request.GET.get('major3')
form = request.GET.get('major4')
form = request.GET.get('major5')
line_chart = pygal.Line(width=1500)
line_chart.title = 'Budget Estimation'  
context = { "chart": line_chart.render_data_uri(),
        'majors': majors}
    return render(request, "website/index.html" , context )

Comment: But i am still unable to get the data

Comment: if you are using request.method  == "POST" than you have to get values also in post like this form = request.POST.get('major1') and for debug purpose you should print that variable like this print(form) and check in your teminal that it prints or not

Comment: and you are taking all the data in same variable in form you should use diffrent variables for diffrent values

Comment: I have changed it but on clicking the submit button the 127.0.0.1:8000 says undefined

Comment: than check that your form method is equal to POST or not

Comment: yes my index.html where form is created is this way <form class="form-row" method="post" >
                        {% csrf_token %}

Comment: try by adding if  request.method == 'POST' only remove if request is_ajax()